# Using jQuery to drag from one .NET grid and drop onto another gridview cell

Tags: jquery, .net, gridview, jquery-ui-draggable

I am developing a scheduler and I need to drag a gridview cell to another gridview cell. I want to use jQuery and I got the drag working just fine, but how do I drag from a .NET gridview and drop to a different gridview cell using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop works on client side. Even though it is a Server control, it will be rendered as HTML to the client( browser). so you should be able to do that.

Make sure you are using the proper selectors. You may need to add some css class name for your cells so that that can be used as the jQuery selector.